# Creating glance image 403 forbidden access

Tags: openstack

I am trying to create an image on my openstack installation with this commande :`glance image-create --name "cirros-0.3.3-x86_64" --disk-format qcow2 --container-format bare -is-public true --progress <cirros-0.3.3-x86_64-disk.img`

but I am getting an error message in html :
   `<html><head><title>403 forbidden access</title>...`
I have check my log file registry log file i have found this :
`2015-01-20 17:52:08.794 2579 INFO glance.wsgi.server [-] Removing dead child 2585
2015-01-20 17:52:08.796 2579 INFO glance.wsgi.server [-] Started child 2671
2015-01-20 17:52:08.797 2579 DEBUG glance.wsgi.server [-] Exited wait_on_children /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/glance/common/wsgi.py:300
2015-01-20 17:52:08.802 2671 INFO glance.wsgi.server [-] (2671) wsgi starting up on http://0.0.0.0:9292/
2015-01-20 17:52:08.803 2671 INFO glance.wsgi.server [-] Child 2671 exiting normally
2015-01-20 17:52:09.149 2673 ERROR glance_store._drivers.filesystem [-] Specify either 'filesystem_store_datadir' or 'filesystem_store_datadirs' option
2015-01-20 17:52:09.150 2673 WARNING glance_store.driver [-] Failed to configure store correctly: None Disabling add method.
2015-01-20 17:52:09.150 2673 ERROR glance_store._drivers.filesystem [-] Specify either 'filesystem_store_datadir' or 'filesystem_store_datadirs' option
2015-01-20 17:52:09.151 2673 WARNING glance_store.driver [-] Failed to configure store correctly: None Disabling add method.
2015-01-20 18:07:52.719 2931 ERROR glance_store._drivers.filesystem [-] Specify either 'filesystem_store_datadir' or 'filesystem_store_datadirs' option
2015-01-20 18:07:52.720 2931 WARNING glance_store.driver [-] Failed to configure store correctly: None Disabling add method.
2015-01-20 18:07:52.720 2931 ERROR glance_store._drivers.filesystem [-] Specify either 'filesystem_store_datadir' or 'filesystem_store_datadirs' option
2015-01-20 18:07:52.721 2931 WARNING glance_store.driver [-] Failed to configure store correctly: None Disabling add method.`

I have already set the filesystem_store_datadir in the config files but I don't understand why it keep showing me this error ?

And sorry for my bad english :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you should remove "-is-public true" from your command line for check your account policy.

Comment: Thinks it's working but how can I configure my account policy to grant this option?

Comment: You might not be admin. How about to add "publicize_image": "", to /etc/glance/policy.json

Answer (score 0):

check file: /etc/glance/glance-registry.conf
and make sure you have set:

```
[paste_deploy]
flavor = keystone
```